# Search Dataset For Value - If Exists Output To Value To Column

Tags: r, rstudio

I'm relatively new to R, taken a few classes, etc. However, I'm trying to do something that has really stumped me and I just can't seem to find an answer to despite it being a task which seems trivial and likely has been done countless times. So I have a dataset and in that dataset is a field "Name" that contains, go figure, names. However, that field includes the persons title in their name, e.g. Mr., Mrs., Miss, etc. What I'm looking to do is create a new column "Title" (I've made this column already) and have that column contain the titles in a numeric form such as Mr. = 1, Mrs. = 2, Miss = 3, etc. The solutions I've found propose new subsets of data but I don't really want that, I want to add a new column in the current dataset with this information. I realize this probably sounds like a trivial task to those experienced with R but it's driving me bonkers. Thank you for any help that can be provided.

Expected output:

```
Name                    Title
Jones, Mr. Frank        1
Jennings, Mrs. Joan     2
Hinker, Miss. Lisa      3
Brant, Mrs. Jane        2
Allin, Mr. Hank         1
Minks, Mr. Jeff         1
Naps, Mr. Tim           1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `gsub` to extract the `Mr/Mrs/Miss` substring from the 'Name' column, convert the `factor` by specifying the `levels` as the `unique` elements in the vector, and finally convert to `numeric` class.

Using `gsub`, we match a particular pattern from the beginning of the string `^`, i.e. match all characters that are not `,` (`[^,]+`) followed by a `,` and zero or more white space (`\\s*`) or (`|`) match the character `.` (`\\.`) followed by characters that are not `.` (`[^.]+`) upto the end of the string (`$`) and replace that with `''` (2nd argument after the `,`).

```
 v1 <- gsub('^[^,]+,\\s*|\\.[^.]+$', '', df1$Name)

 df1$Title <- as.numeric(factor(v1, levels=unique(v1)))
```

NOTE: We can also specify the order in the `levels`, i.e. `factor(v1, levels= c('Mr', 'Mrs', 'Miss'))`.  In the example provided, the `unique` gives the correct order as in the expected output.

Or we can `match` the `vector` with the `unique` elements in that vector.

```
df1$Title <- match(v1, unique(v1))
df1
#                 Name Title
#1    Jones, Mr. Frank     1
#2 Jennings, Mrs. Joan     2
#3  Hinker, Miss. Lisa     3
#4    Brant, Mrs. Jane     2
#5     Allin, Mr. Hank     1
#6     Minks, Mr. Jeff     1
#7       Naps, Mr. Tim     1
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Name = c("Jones, Mr. Frank", "Jennings, Mrs. Joan", 
"Hinker, Miss. Lisa", "Brant, Mrs. Jane", "Allin, Mr. Hank", 
"Minks, Mr. Jeff", "Naps, Mr. Tim")), .Names = "Name", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: When trying that I get the following error "Error in factor(v1, levels = unique(v1)) : object 'v1' not found"

Comment: @Ryan Have you tried `v1 <- gsub('^[^,]+,\\s*|\\.[^.]+$', '', df1$Name)`

Comment: Seems to work! Much appreciatated, any possibility you can explain the logic in the gsub('^[^,]+,\\s*|\\.[^.]+$', '', df1$Name) part?

Comment: @Ryan Thanks, I updated the post with some explanation.  Hope it helps.  Also you can read `?regex`